# Selection changed event also called Lostfocus event?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, listbox

NET C# ,
In my windows phone 7.5 application , I want to make visible the application bar if any item has selected .. So I am making it visible in selected change event. But what is happening in my code is when ever selection change it also triggers LostFocus event and in that event I am making selected index = 0. 
Now the resultant of the code is when ever I select any item , application bar gets visible then automatically invisible ( because of lost focus event).
Following is the piece of code .

```
 private void ShopingListItemDetails_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ShopingListItemDetails.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            int selind = ShopingListItemDetails.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }

    private void ShopingListItemDetails_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
        ShopingListItemDetails.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

I am just at start with .NET C#(XAML) so assuming that selection change event is also triggering LostFocus event.

Please help me what is the real problem behind.Thanks
Zauk

Comment: Try to use OnHold event instead of SelectionChanged event and Use Context Menu instead of Appbar. That may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following hack. Initialize a variable, say selectChanged to False initially in the xaml.cs. In SelectionChanged function change it to True. Now, in the LostFocus function do processing only if the selectChanged variable is false, and if it is true set it back to False

```
Boolean selectChanged=false;
private void ShopingListItemDetails_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ShopingListItemDetails.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
        int selind = ShopingListItemDetails.SelectedIndex;
        selectChanged=true;
    }
}

private void ShopingListItemDetails_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!selectChanged) 
    {
        ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
        ShopingListItemDetails.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    selectChanged=false;
}
```

I think this should solve your problem.